# Handling a selection

Tags: python

Allows the user to make an input of the question they would like to choose and the difficulty they wish to complete in.

The code below is very repetitive meaning the if and elif statements have the same coding but varies on the user options and difficulty they have chosen.

So, is there a way to shorten this code since it is inefficient repeating the same code?

```
options = input("Choose 'a' for arithmetic or 'c' for computing: ")
diffCulty = input ("Choose 'e' for easy , 'm' for medium , 'h' for hard: ")

if options == "a" and diffCulty == "e":
    questOne = int(input("What is 4+4?"))

elif options == "a" and diffCulty == "m":
    questTwo = int(input("What is 8x8+4-2?"))

elif options == "a" and diffCulty == "h":
    questThree = int(input("What is 8+4+3-2x8+2?"))
```

Comment: Well for starters I would create a list or dictionary to put the questions inside and then you could draw a random question of that difficulty from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic practice is to use a mapping. Here you need a mapping for *options* and another mapping for *difficulty*.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
options = input("Choose 'a' for arithmetic or 'c' for computing: ")
difficulty = input("Choose 'e' for easy , 'm' for medium , 'h' for hard: ")

mapping = {'a': {
    'e': "What is 4+4?",
    'm': "What is 8x8+4-2?",
    'h': "What is 8+4+3-2x8+2?"
}}

question = mapping[options][difficulty]
answer = int(input(question))
```

Of course, you also need to store the expected answers.

Comment: If I was to do another 'mapping' for computing it wouldn't work because of a keyError.

Answer (score 4):

Since there is no problem with the code and is more stylistic, each person might have their own view on the matter. One way to do it is:

```
options_diffCulty = {
    "a": {
        "e": "What is 4+4?",
        "m": "What is 8x8+4-2?",
        "h": "What is 8+4+3-2x8+2?"
    }
}
options = input("Choose 'a' for arithmetic or 'c' for computing: ")
diffCulty = input("Choose 'e' for easy , 'm' for medium , 'h' for hard: ")
questOne = int(input(options_diffCulty[options][diffCulty]))
```

You can also use [yaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) to give a more hierarchical structure to your questions like:

```
a:
  e: What is 4+4?
  m: What is 8x8+4-2?
  h: What is 8+4+3-2x8+2?
b:
  e: What is 4+4?
  m: What is 8x8+4-2?
  h: What is 8+4+3-2x8+2?
```

This can be loaded into your program with a simple `options_diffCulty = yaml.load(open("your yaml").read())` and the continue from there. But thats just me.

Comment: nice yaml reference, +1

Comment: yeah, you can nest your answers and stuff. It's pretty handy. Of course a `JSON` file can also be used but the structure gets a bit complicated if you want arrays and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about something like this:

```
import random

options = input("Choose 'a' for arithmetic or 'c' for computing: ")
diffCulty = input ("Choose 'e' for easy , 'm' for medium , 'h' for hard: ")
questions = int(input("How many? "))

qa = {"a": {
        "e":[{"q":"What is 4+4?","a":8},
             {"q":"What is 5+4?","a":9}],
        "m":[{"q":"What is 8x8+4-2?","a":66}],
        "h":[{"q":"What is 8+4+3-2x8+2?","a":1}]
    }}


while questions:
    array = qa[options][diffCulty]
    randomint = random.randint(0,len(array)-1)

    q = array[randomint]["q"]
    a = array[randomint]["a"]


    if int(input(q)) == a:
        print("Right")
    else:
        print("Wrong")

    questions -= 1
```

---

And to create the question dictionary you could have a simple spreadsheet converted to csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
from collections import defaultdict

csv = """type,difficulty,question,answer
a,e,What is 4+4?,8
a,e,What is 4+5?,9
a,m,What is 4+4-2*2?,4"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv))

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for item in df.to_dict(orient="records"):
    d[item["type"]][item["difficulty"]].append({"q":item["question"],"a":int(item["answer"])})
```